# Get a json array inside another json array using key

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am working on application using spring boot angular js. In this I am dealing with json array and json object to construct tree using abn-tree.

Tree constructing fine. As this tree will be updated on click of each node, means children will be added on runtime as on click by loading from database.

Tree JSON is like :

```
 [{"parent":"Title-1","expanded":true,"label":"Title-1","children":[
    {"parent":"Title-1","expanded":true,"label":"Chapter-I", "children":[
        {"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-1"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-10"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-100"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-11"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-12"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-13"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-14"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-140"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-49"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-5"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-50"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-7"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-75"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-8"},{"parent":"Chapter-I","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-9"}]},
    {"parent":"Title-1","expanded":true,"label":"Chapter-II","children":[
        {"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-200"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-201"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-202"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-203"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-204"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-205"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-209"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-210"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-211"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-285"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-286"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-287"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-288"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-289"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-290"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-300"},{"parent":"Chapter-II","expanded":false,"children":[],"label":"Part-301"}]}]
}]
```

The above returned to UI and tree displayed, so I am constructing this json in backend resource classes to avoid code in js files.

This json will grow more as each of Part will add Subpart / Subgroups etc...next subpart will add their children. So Children of part..subpart.. will add object to load their children.

Traversing of this json is getting long as it growing bigger. Loops are also increasing. Is there any easy way to get jsonarray of given string to add more child on it without looping.

Like I want children of Part-200, I just provide name of node and get json array for Part-200 without looping and iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Please make the JSON data as simple as possible. May be it is huge when you get response from an API. Write some functions to simplify the JSON and store them in the scope variables before coming to the view level. It will be complicated with loops like `ng-repeat`. Every time we may not wish to go to the `loops`. So, make sure that all the required data to be shown in the view should be in scope variables such that we can access them easily from the view

Comment: Complete json will return to UI and stored in a scope variable. I am having issue in java side, nothing has to be done with ui i.e java script angular side, it just have to show data returned from resource java class. I want convenient way to get the node so that I can update it with its child.